# How Do You Send Ether to Another Contract's Payable Function?

Tags: solidity

I am trying to send pay a dividend token contract Ether from another contract using the deposit() function in the contract below. I have found conflicting answers based on different compiler versions.

Below is the token contract that accepts deposits which are paid out as dividends:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.19;

contract RobustDividendToken {

    string public name = "Robust Dividend Token";
    string public symbol = "DIV";
    uint8 public decimals = 18;

    uint256 public totalSupply = 1000000 * (uint256(10) ** decimals);

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function RobustDividendToken() public {
        // Initially assign all tokens to the contract's creator.
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, totalSupply);
    }

    uint256 public scaling = uint256(10) ** 8;

    mapping(address => uint256) public scaledDividendBalanceOf;

    uint256 public scaledDividendPerToken;

    mapping(address => uint256) public scaledDividendCreditedTo;

    function update(address account) internal {
        uint256 owed =
            scaledDividendPerToken - scaledDividendCreditedTo[account];
        scaledDividendBalanceOf[account] += balanceOf[account] * owed;
        scaledDividendCreditedTo[account] = scaledDividendPerToken;
    }

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint256 value);

    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowance;

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool success) {
        require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= value);

        update(msg.sender);
        update(to);

        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;

        Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
        require(value <= balanceOf[from]);
        require(value <= allowance[from][msg.sender]);

        update(from);
        update(to);

        balanceOf[from] -= value;
        balanceOf[to] += value;
        allowance[from][msg.sender] -= value;
        Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }

    uint256 public scaledRemainder = 0;

    function deposit() public payable {
        // scale the deposit and add the previous remainder
        uint256 available = (msg.value * scaling) + scaledRemainder;

        scaledDividendPerToken += available / totalSupply;

        // compute the new remainder
        scaledRemainder = available % totalSupply;
    }

    function withdraw() public {
        update(msg.sender);
        uint256 amount = scaledDividendBalanceOf[msg.sender] / scaling;
        scaledDividendBalanceOf[msg.sender] %= scaling;  // retain the remainder
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint256 value)
        public
        returns (bool success)
    {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }

}
```

My contract works except for this operation. If I were to simple send a random address with: `randomaddr.transfer(this.balance);` then we have no problems.

However, when I try  `TokenContractAddress.call.value(this.balance)();` or I try `TokenContractAddress.deposit.value(this.balance)();` the Tx fails.

I have tried importing the contract and some other syntax too, but I get the same error. What is the best way to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following won't succeed because the target contract doesn't define a payable fallback function:

```
TokenContractAddress.call.value(this.balance)();
```

Your other attempt is correct, assuming `TokenContractAddress` is a variable of type `RobustDividendToken` that points to the deployed `RobustDividendToken` contract:

```
TokenContractAddress.deposit.value(this.balance)();
```

If this is failing, please provide the full code that you're using and describe how you're deploying each contract and how `TokenContractAddress` gets its value.

Here's a test contract I made that is able to successfully call `RobustDividendToken`'s `deposit` function:

```
contract Test {
    RobustDividendToken token;

    function Test(RobustDividendToken _token) public {
        token = _token;
    }

    function deposit() public payable {
        token.deposit.value(msg.value)();
    }
}
```

I deployed `RobustDividendToken` via Remix, then copied its address and deployed `Test` passing that address as a constructor parameter. (Be sure to pass the address as a quoted string.) Then I set the `value` field in Remix to a non-zero value and called `deposit` on `Test`. The transaction succeeded.

Comment: I couldn't get that to compile. What does ```RobustDividendToken token``` do? Should I be importing RobustDividendToken above?

I just have ```TokenContract = 0x2274cbe6BC66a2Ce7EeBcC80b6F8162E73F78c76;``` now in my contract's constructor and ```TokenContract``` is an address type. I think this must be the thing I'm messing up.

Comment: Yes, you need `RobustDividendToken` available somehow (defined in the same file, imported, or just defined as an interface). Then you can do `RobustDividendToken token = 0x2274cb...`.

Comment: See https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2018/02/02/writing-a-token-sale-contract/ if you choose to use an interface.

Comment: Read that before posting, but I suspect it's the right answer. :-) Hopefully sleep helps. Great site. There is a lot of fragmented documentation on the syntax. I understand mappings and its one way nature now from the dividend contract, so that's a win!

Comment: Got it to work! I just pasted the RobustDividendToken contract above, and used this: ```RobustDividendToken public TokenContract = RobustDividendToken(0x2274cbe6BC66a2Ce7EeBcC80b6F8162E73F78c76);``` and then ```TokenContract.deposit.value(TokenCommission)();``` to ship the Ether over to the dividend contract.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the syntax from user19510 work.

Let me answer this specific question

> How do You Send Ether to Another Contract's Payable Function?

with a generic example:

If you have a contract called A, with a function `foo()` that is payable. And you have a contract called B with a function `boo()` that wants to call this function `foo` from Contract A and needs to send ether to it, then

```
function boo() public payable {
   a.foo{value: msg.value}();
}
```

Please make sure that boo is also **payable**.

And note `a` is a variable of Contract Type A.

The round brackets () after the curly brackets {} take the arguments of your function foo.